# Spring Boot Thymeleaf "Cannot find template location"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Using Spring Boot with Gradle, I can't get it to resolve templates. *Any* devitation for `spring.thymeleaf.prefix` other than `classpath:/` causes it to throw a startup error that it can't find the location, and no matter where I stick a file in the project directory, it fails to locate the file.

Comment: By default, the directory is resources/templates - did u try it?

Comment: I did. Nothing.

Comment: What "other" value have you tried, and how did you change the directory structure of your project to accommodate this?

Comment: I can use `classpath:/tpl/` and then put a `tpl` folder (with an `index.html` file) _anywhere_ in the project directory and it will never accept it as being valid regardless of where it's located. It flat-out refuses to acknowledge it.